# Access Denied to API Version: API20120917 (CloudFormation/RDS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

I tried to create an Oracle database instance in Amazon RDS but I have this error with CloudFormation and I can't find a solution.

Can anyone help with this problem?

> Resource handler returned message: "Access Denied to API Version: API20120917 (Service: Rds, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 172bd747-8158-4b30-8222-efaca96267e2)" (RequestToken: 5d0b9b3a-4185-1b76-e6d3-9aab9896c076, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)

Comment: Have you tried created it via the console? Does this also give you an error?